# Facebook API in machine readable format

Tags: facebook, api, swagger, apiblueprint, raml

Where I can find the Facebook API in a format like http://swagger.io, https://apiblueprint.org or http://raml.org?

I want to read and request the facebook server (api) "half-atomatic". My script knowns how to interact with the facebook server. And thats why I need the Facebook API in a machine-readable format.

Thank you for any hint.
Cheers Tobias

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. How the FB API works, is described under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: I want to read and request the facebook server (api) "half-atomatic". My script knowns how to interact with the facebook server. And thats why I need the Facebook API in a machine-readable format.

Comment: Still doesn’t make sense to me. Define “machine-readable” – what exactly is your machine supposed to ”read” and how? The FB API delivers JSON data for most endpoints, and that should be ”machine-readable” enough by any common definition.

Comment: I'll try to explain it with the goal of swagger: The goal of Swagger is to define a standard, language-agnostic interface to REST APIs which allows both humans and computers to discover and understand the capabilities of the service without access to source code, documentation, or through network traffic inspection. When properly defined via Swagger, a consumer can understand and interact with the remote service with a minimal amount of implementation logic. Similar to what interfaces have done for lower-level programming, Swagger removes the guesswork in calling the service.

Comment: I don’t think that anything like that exists for the FB API.

Comment: As @CBroe said, unfortunately this is not existing for the Facebook Graph API. But you should be able to create it from the FB docs manually...

Answer (score -4):

From what I've seen of Swagger, it sounds like you're looking for something like Facebook's [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). It lets you browse the graph API methods visually, whilst manually creating your own queries and sending them to it.

Comment: Swagger / OpenAPI is a specification about how to write a machine readable API. Graph Explorer has nothing to do with it, despite that you could Swagger / OpenAPI manifests to generate a UI like Graph Explorer.